# How do I make a personal view a default view?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view

Is there a way out-of-the-box in SharePoint 2010 for a user to make their personal view their default view? There has to be a way - am I not seeing it?

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, to my knowledge.

If you want to dive a little deeper, one possible way to provide this capability would be to add

```
<meta name="WebPartPageDefaultViewPersonal"/>
```

to the head of the web-part page where the list is being displayed.